# Specify custom formatting for html tags in VS Code

Tags: html, formatting, visual-studio-code

I like **html** formatted in a specific way. For example working with Telerik's grid (which can have many attributes) I like it like this:

```html
<kendo-grid [data]="myGrid"
            [height]="510"
            [pageSize]="prjState.take" 
            [skip]="prjState.skip" 
            [pageable]="true"
            [sortable]="true" 
            [sort]="prjState.sort" 
            [filter]="prjState.filter" 
            [filterable]="true" 
            
            (edit)="editHandler('prj',$event)"
            (cancel)="cancelHandler($event)" 
            (save)="saveHandler('prj',$event)" 
            (dataStateChange)="onPrjStateChange($event)">
```

If I format it like this in VS Code and hit **Shift** + **Alt** + **F**, the formatter deletes all my custom formatting:

```html
<kendo-grid [data]="myGrid" [pageSize]="prjState.take" [skip]="prjState.skip" [pageable]="true" (edit)="editHandler('prj',$event)"
                            (cancel)="cancelHandler($event)" (save)="saveHandler('prj',$event)" [sortable]="true" [height]="510"
                            [sort]="prjState.sort" [filter]="prjState.filter" [filterable]="true" (dataStateChange)="onPrjStateChange($event)">
```

**2 questions:**

1. Is it possible to stop VS Code from reformatting my kendo-grid tag?
2. Is it possible to modify VS Code so it formats kendo-grid tags the way i indicated?

**What I tried (with no results):**

- adding **kendo-grid** tag to **html.format.contentUnformatted** setting in settings.json file
- adding **kendo-grid** tag to **html.format.unformatted** setting in settings.json file

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the User settings `Preferences` > `User Settings` setting

```
"html.format.wrapAttributes": "force-aligned"
```

Will make all HTML tags behave like your example. You can also set

```
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"editor.formatOnPaste": true
```

To make it work automatically on save and paste.